# Intellij - jsx double quotes not applied

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript-eslint, prettier-eslint

I am using intellij and I have started a react typescript project with vite, have added eslint and prettier, as well as lint-staged. After initially having single quotes for everything I wanted to configure double quotes for jsx. I have set up the `prettier` config file like this:

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "plugins": [
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"
  ]
}
```

And the `eslintrc.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "camelcase": "error",
    "spaced-comment": "error",
    "jsx-quotes": [
      "error",
      "prefer-double"
    ],
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single"
    ],
    "no-duplicate-imports": "error"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    }
  }
}
```

But, whenever I save or run reformat code in intellij with double quotes it reformats it back to single quotes, like this line in my `App.tsx`:

```
<div className='p-2 bg-blue-500 text-white'>
```

In `package.json` file I have this scripts:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json}": "npm run format --",
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}": "npm run lint:fix --"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}' --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}'",
    "format": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json}' --config ./.prettierrc",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
```

If I run prettier script code is correctly formatted to double quotes. It seems like Intellij has a wrong setup for some reason. I have tried to invalidated caches and restart it, but it is always the same thing if I save something in the editor it is reformatted to single quotes again.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Your prettier config specifies single quotes, while your eslint config specifies double. I don't know which one IntelliJ cares about, but removing that line from the prettierrc may help.

Comment: @ZacAnger https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html says for quotes options - JSX quotes ignore this option. Besides if that option was the problem then running the package script wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-50619](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50619/Prettier-is-converting-vue-html-attributes-to-single-quotes.-Only-want-JavaScript-strings-to-be-single-quote.), please vote for it to get notified on any progress